# Convert Angular 1 script to angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this code written in angular 1 and i need to convert it to angular 2
and my all other angular scripts are written in angular 2 .

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('testCtrl', testCtrl);

testCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function testCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.categoryTypes = ['M-Trouser-Denim ','M-Trouser-Cotton','M-T shirt-Cotton','M-T shirt-Silk','M-T shirt-Polyester','M-Shirt-Cotton','M-Shirt-Silk','M-Shirt-Polyester','M-Short','Blouses','Skirts','Saree','FM-Trouser-Denim','FM-Trouser-Cotton','FM-T shirt-Silk','FM-T shirt-Polyester','FM-Shirt-Cotton','FM-Shirt-Silk','FM-Shirt-Polyester','FM-Short'];

    $scope.clothCount = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']


    $scope.itemSet = {
        item: []
    };

    $scope.addNewItem = function() {
        $scope.itemSet.item.push({});
    };

    $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
        $scope.itemSet.item.splice(index, 1);
    };
}})();
```

please help me

Comment: Instead of converting, why not learn Angular2? https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: i wish i could , but i have less time to finish the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might want to look into migration.

Resources:

- https://angular.io/guide/upgrade
- https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference